# What is 'this' used for in C# language?

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, this

I've read open source c# code and there is a lot of strange grammar (to me).

They declare method arguments with the **this** keyword like this:

**this object @object**

What does it mean?

If I remove 'this' keyword where is before the data type, then will it work differently?

Comment: C# has very nice grammar, in fact, if you compare it to C++.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sounds like an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx).

The `@` symbol allows the variable name to be the same as a C# keyword - I tend to avoid them like the plague personally.

If you remove the `this` keyword, it will no longer be an extension method, just a static method. Depending on the calling code syntax, it may no longer compile, for example:

```
public static class IntegerMethods
{
    public static int Add(this int i, int value)
    {
        return i + value;
    }
}

int i = 0;

// This is an "extension method" call, and will only compile against extension methods.
i = i.Add(2); 
// This is a standard static method call.
i = IntegerMethods.Add(i, 2);
```

The compiler will simply translate all "extension method calls" into standard static method calls at any rate, but extension method calls will still only work against valid extension methods as per the `this type name` syntax.

**Some guidelines**

These are my own, but I find they are useful.

- Discoverability of extension methods can be a problem, so be mindful of the namespace you choose to contain them in. We have *very useful* stuff under .NET namespaces such as `System.Collections` or whatever. Less useful but  otherwise "common" stuff tends to go under `Extensions.<namespace of extended type>` such that discoverability is at least consistent via convention.
- Try not to extend often used types in broad scope, you don't want `MyFabulousExtensionMethod` appearing on `object` throughout your app. If you *need* to, either constrain the scope (namespace) to be *very* specific, or bypass extension methods and use a static class directly - these won't pollute the type metadata in IntelliSense.
- In extension methods, "this" can be `null` (due to how they compile into static method calls) so be careful and don't assume that "this" is not null (from the calling side this looks like a successful method call on a null target).

These are optional and not exhaustive, but I find they usually fall under the banner of "good" advice. YMMV.

Comment: The only time I've used them is for Extension methods, to call the `this` parameter `@this`. Although I'm coming to the conclusion that's "too cute".

Comment: @MatthewWatson, I just call the `this` parameter `self`. Works.

Answer (score 4):

The 'this type name' syntax is used for extension methods.

For example if I wanted to add a `UnCamelCase` method to a string (so I could do `"HelloWorld".UnCamelCase()` to produce "Hello World` - I'd write this:

```
public static string UnCamelCase(this string text)
{
    /*match any instances of a lower case character followed by an upper case 
     * one, and replace them with the same characters with a space between them*/
    return Regex.Replace(text, "([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
}
```

`this string text` means the specific instance of the string that you're working with, and text is the identifier for it.

The @ syntax allows for variable names that are ordinarily reserved.